# How to execute an action after all Ajax requests complete using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to accomplish this where I have two [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) calls. I want to execute another Ajax call ONLY when the first two are completely done. However, when I make the call to my first two, the third one is being executed as well. Below is my code.

```
/**
 * Triggers all the partners to search for offers.
 */

function PREQUAL_OFFERS() {
    var hughes = HUGHES();
    var ctl = CTL();

    $.when(hughes, ctl).then(function () {
        ENGINE_OFFERS(); // Executes after all previous Ajax calls are done.
    });
}

function ATT() {}

function HUGHES() {
    console.log("Initialized hughes()");
    var data = $("#searchPackages").serialize();
    var requestOffers = $.ajax({
            url : "/isgov3/index.php/HUGHES/ajax/PreQual",
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "html",
            cache : false,
            data : data,
    });
    requestOffers.success(function (data) {});
    requestOffers.fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {});
}

function CTL() {
    console.log("Initialized CTL()");
    var data = $("#searchPackages").serialize();
    var requestOffers = $.ajax({
            url : "/isgov3/index.php/CTL/ajax/PreQual",
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "html",
            cache : false,
            data : data,
    });
    requestOffers.success(function (data) {});
    requestOffers.fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {});
}

function ENGINE_OFFERS() {
    console.log("Called Engine");
    var Offers = $.get({
            url : "/isgov3/index.php/ENGINE/engine",
            dataType : "html",
            cache : false,
    });

    Offers.success(function (data) {
        $("#MyTab-Menu_tab_12").html(data);
    });
    Offers.fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {});
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `return` statements in `CTL` and `HUGHES`

Comment: How about a little refactor.....remember that ajax is async, so in order to accomplish such thing you need to chain your ajax calls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HUGHES()` and `CTL()` will both have to `return` a deferred/promise for `$.when()` to use, such as the `jqXHR` provided by `$.ajax()`:

```
function HUGHES(callback) {
    // ...
    var requestOffers = $.ajax({ ... });

    // ...
    return requestOffers;
}

function CTL(callback) {
    // ...

    return requestOffers;
}
```

Without a `return` statement in either function, `var hughes` and `var ctrl` are both being assigned `undefined`, which `$.when()` treats as an immediate resolution/success value:

```
$.when(undefined, undefined).then(function () {
    console.log(arguments); // { 0: undefined, 1: undefined }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a callback function for each in such way a certain stuff will wait for that other stuff to finish before execution. So in this case ENGINE_OFFERS will only be executed if HUGHES and CTL are already done.

```
function PREQUAL_OFFERS() {

    HUGHES(function(data) {
        CTL(function(data) {
            ENGINE_OFFERS();
        });
    });
}

function ATT() {}

function HUGHES(callback) {
    console.log("Initialized hughes()");
    var data = $("#searchPackages").serialize();
    var requestOffers = $.ajax({
            url : "/isgov3/index.php/HUGHES/ajax/PreQual",
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "html",
            cache : false,
            data : data,
        });

    requestOffers.success(function (data) { callback(data); });

    requestOffers.fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) { callback(error); });

}

function CTL(callback) {
    console.log("Initialized CTL()");
    var data = $("#searchPackages").serialize();
    var requestOffers = $.ajax({
            url : "/isgov3/index.php/CTL/ajax/PreQual",
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "html",
            cache : false,
            data : data,
        });

    requestOffers.success(function (data) { callback(data); });

    requestOffers.fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) { callback(data); });
}

function ENGINE_OFFERS() {
    console.log("Called Engine");
    var Offers = $.get({
            url : "/isgov3/index.php/ENGINE/engine",
            dataType : "html",
            cache : false,
        });

    Offers.success(function (data) {

        $("#MyTab-Menu_tab_12").html(data);

    });

    Offers.fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {});
```